# Android Share Intent Completed

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, twitter, share

I have a simple share intent to allow users to post to social / text msg:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Is there any way to check if user actually completed the action successfully (shared via twitter as an example)or just exited out by hitting the back button ?

Comment: You tagged Facebook. You want to know if they shared something on Facebook? Why?

Comment: Looking too give users points for sharing via social. Obviously its an external application at that point but I was wondering if the OS returns anything back via intents or any other mechanisms.

Comment: That is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy. You are not allowed to incentivize sharing

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing that out. I'm going to have to review the TOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for two reasons:

1. Just because the user continued past the chooser to some app does not mean that the user "completed the action successfully" (e.g., might have chosen not to actually do anything in the Twitter app once there)
2. You have no way of finding out whether the user actually continued past the chooser in the first place

You could address the second problem by implementing your own chooser, using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to have to integrate with Twitter API to do this then. Twitter Fabric took a while to install and have it working correctly, but that seems as the quickest approach for my purposes.